# How to make div position Responsive - Css

Tags: html, css

i had our webite which built with wordpress and i am using AVada theme,

i am using animation instead of slider and small typriting text, both of them i am using css position to be one on the right and the other on left side with little positon from logo

But when the screen size differ the text positon not same as attched photo 
so could you please help me on that

```
[bodymovin anim_id="1332" loop="true" style="right:-30%"]
```

Passion of [typed id='1459']
 Savvy, versatile and structured – but still loose enough to 
 allow the creative space to flow.

[neopplanet website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ0xZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: already solved it by plugin for animation

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin: 0 auto 
This will make your text located automatically even by changing the size of windows